# Sencha Touch build application with all-classes

Tags: javascript, android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to speed up my application using the all classes method described [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/?print=/guide/building).

I was updating my index.html with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Twitter</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/application.css" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="touch/sencha-touch-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Building that wouln't work. The error is:

> > [INF] Writing content to C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\Sencha Touch\testapp/c ordova/www/index.html [ERR] [ERR] BUILD FAILED [ERR]
> >     java.lang.NullPointerException [ERR]   at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccesso [ERR]
> >     rImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [ERR] [ERR] Total
> >     time: 7 seconds [ERR] The following error occurred while executing
> >     this line: C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\Sencha
> >     Touch\testapp.sencha\app\build-impl.xml :396: The following error
> >     occurred while executing this line: C:\Spree Github
> >     Repository\Phone\Sencha Touch\testapp.sencha\app\page-impl.xml: 235:
> >     The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Spree
> >     Github Repository\Phone\Sencha
> >     Touch\testapp.sencha\app\page-impl.xml: 154: The following error
> >     occurred while executing this line: C:\Spree Github
> >     Repository\Phone\Sencha Touch\testapp.sencha\app\page-impl.xml: 17:
> >     The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Spree
> >     Github Repository\Phone\Sencha
> >     Touch\testapp.sencha\app\page-impl.xml: 18:
> >     java.lang.NullPointerException

The index.html that is working looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>TestApp</title>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js">       </script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**The question is: Why is my project failing to build?** I was following all the steps provided in the [tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/?print=/guide/building), but it wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you missed the step where you are trying to use sencha CMD? What are you doing exactly.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I missed. I found out that Sencha CMD does that all automatically. However, the app is still slow on my phone. That is because I am running a custom Android 4.4 build on an old Android 2.3 phone. No good for Sencha Touch!

Comment: Hehe, you want to know what slow is: HTC One with Android 4.4 :)

Comment: Haha :D I think mine is slower tho, Motorola defy.